# Redirect pip, setuptools, and everything related to private PyPI repository

Tags: python, pypi

I want all my PyPI-related queries to be run against a private server. This server hosts some company packages and proxies requests to the real PyPI server when it cannot serve the packages directly.

I am able to make `pip` read this repository, via `export PIP_INDEX_URL='https://example.org/pypi/simple'`.

However, when I try to install a package that depends on other private packages (via `python setup.py install)`, the queries go straight to `pypi.python.org`.

- I tried setting up `.pydistutils.cfg`, this does nothing.
- I tried editing `setup.py` to include `dependency_links=['https://example.org/pypi/simple/pkgname'],` - but here I have to specify full url for each package. I do not want to do this.
- I tried editing `.pypirc` to have `pypi` point to the required url. No luck here either.

Which configuration file or environment variable controls the index url for `setup.py`?

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://gemfury.com/help/pypi-server/#upload-modules) by any chance? It looks like it might work.

Comment: I tried editing .pypirc, but it seems to have no effect. The case described in the linked article concerns itself with uploading the packages. the `-r repo` argument is not available for `install` subcommand.

Answer (score -1):

Edit `~/.pip/pip.conf`:

```
[global]
trusted-host = private-server
index = http://user:password@private-server
index-url = http://user:password@private-server
```

Comment: The environment variable PIP_INDEX_URL I tried using corresponds to the index-url key in pip.conf (documented here: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#config-file). Using your pip.conf did not help, setuptools still reads only from pypi.python.org.